# How to synchronize multi-databases to one central database in remote servers?

Tags: mysql, oracle, security, synchronization, integration

I have a project where there are multi-sites (1500 client sites) each contain an Oracle database, and 1 datacenter with MySQL database where all the data from all client sites should reside and kept sync. The project scope is to achieve the synchronization between the datacenter and client sites.

Accordingly, I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there a utility/tool to implement this integration & synchronization between Oracle and MySQL databases?
2. What is best way to protect data when transferring/ sending using the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a number of tools that can be used to achieve something like this, but the best solution will depend on your organization's technical needs and its budget (don't underestimate the importance of this one.) I am an Oracle DBA by trade, and while I do some work in MySql, these will be Oracle-centric recommendations. Just FYI.

For #1. I would recommend checking out [Oracle Golden Gate](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/goldengate.html) and [Oracle Data Guard](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/high-availability/dataguard.html).

Golden Gate is a data integration and replication and package that allows you to sync data across multiple databases in near real-time. Using Golden Gate, you can replicate data, transactions, and DDL changes across multiple kinds of environments. It can be difficult to set up, but once it's in place, it will pay for itself many times over if you are able to leverage it in a way that makes sense for your needs. This is probably going to be the most cost effective solution (in terms of level of effort, cost, etc,) but it will be costly and will probably require training if you and your staff are not familiar with it.

Data Guard is also an Oracle technology, but its more for primary/standby database set ups. It essentially allows you to create two databases - one as a primary database where your data transactions are occurring, and one as a standby database where those transactions are replicated, also in near real-time. I like Data Guard because it can allow you to to seamlessly transition between primary and standby without it necessarily being known to the end user. For example, let's say a user connects to your Primary Database, but the file system where the primary lives becomes corrupt for some reason. You can set it up so that the database will automatically move that user's connection to the standby and allow them to complete their transaction, all without an interruption on their end.

I bring up data guard because rather than having your cilent sites replicate directly to your data center, you might want to consider setting up Data Guard so that the primary databases can reside on the client side, but that your standby databases reside on the side of the data center. This will do two things - 1. create a local copy of your client databases so that in a catastrophe, you can easily recover. and 2. decrease the likelihood of things like network latency causing issues. If your replication strategy relies on those client side databases always being up and accessible, you will run into issues when folks at those client sites run into problems. With Data Guard, you can protect yourself from some of that risk by syncing with the standby databases - meaning instead of changes coming from client -> directly to data center to sync, it would go from client primary database -> data center standby database -> data center to sync. Your security and networking teams will also likely prefer a solution like this, but that may vary.

For #2. Whenever you're moving data across the internet, you want to use basic things like Encryption, SSL, certificate authentication, firewalls, VPNs, etc. Beyond that, you also want to be sure you are following the guidelines and regulations that have been set in your region. For example, if you are working with banking or financial data, there may be laws and regulation in place that stipulate the minimum requirements for moving that data across the open internet. Likewise, if you are working with medical or healthcare data, there is probably a different set of minimum requirements for that industry as well. Your organization should be able to connect you with resources to find those requirements, but at the end of the day, this responsibility to adhere to regulations (if there are any) will fall on whoever is setting it up - most likely you. Make sure you are aware of the type of data being moved, as well as any legal implications revolving around that data, and set your technical requirements based on that.

If there aren't any rules/regulations for the data you work with (let's say, you're just moving publicly available data that has no need for protection,) you can just do what works - just be sure that you are doing it in a secure way as to not compromise the client sites or your data center.